# Ruby module method that accepts file path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, filepath

I am new to Ruby, and working on a small program where I need to create a module with a method that takes file path and read the content of the file. 
 Following is the code for the module.

```
module Model

def self.generate(file_path)
    file_name = File.basename("file_path")
    puts File.read(file_name)
  #return ex. Person class 

end
end
```

When I try to call the method like Model.generate("/Users/myname/Rubyfolder/mytext.txt/"), I get the following error:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - file_path
from ./code_generation.rb:5:in `read'
from ./code_generation.rb:5:in `generate'
from (irb):34
```

I guess that it is maybe a problem with how I describe path... but I have no idea how to make it work. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"file_path"` is a string. You are likely to use variable `file_path` (w/o quotes) here.

Answer (score 2):

It is the problem:

```
file_name = File.basename("file_path")
```

Change it to this:

```
file_name = File.basename(file_path)
```

`file_path` is a parameter, while `"file_path"` is a string, which is probably not a name of an existing file.